# Python simple turtle progam

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am having trouble trying to finish a python turtle program. When I attempt to input x and y coordinates as well as a radius value for the function like 
t.drawSnowman(x = 25,y = 25,radius = 25) the program misbehaves when I input values.but if I leave out the parameters above and instead just use t.drawSnowman() the program works as intended but I am not able to create various instances of the snowman.

I would really like help trying to figure out how to input the parameters and still have the program function.

here's my code

```
import turtle

class MyTurtle(turtle.Turtle):
""""""


def __init__(self):
    """Turtle Constructor"""
    turtle.Turtle.__init__(self, shape="turtle")

def drawNose(self, x=0, y=0, radius = 15, circle_color = "black"):
    '''draw nose '''
    self.pendown()
    self.goto(-(radius) * (0.25),(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius))
    self.goto(0,(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius)+(radius * (0.25)))
    self.goto((radius) * (0.25),(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius))
    self.goto(0,(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius))
    self.penup()

def leftEye(self, x=0, y=0, radius = 15, circle_color = "black"):
    '''draw left eye'''
    self.pendown()
    self.circle(radius*(.25))
    self.penup()
def rightEye(self, x=0, y=0, radius = 15, circle_color = "black"):
    '''draw right eye'''
    self.pendown()
    self.circle(radius*(.25))
    self.penup()
def bottomOfHat(self, x=0, y=0, radius = 15, circle_color = "black"):
    ''' draw the long part of the hat at the bottom '''
    self.goto(0,(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius * 2))
    self.pendown()
    self.goto(-(radius),(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius * 2))
    self.goto(-(radius),(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius * 2)+(radius * (0.5)))
    self.goto(radius,(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius * 2)+(radius * (0.5)))
    self.goto(radius,(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius * 2))
    self.goto(0,(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius * 2))
    self.penup()

def topOfHat(self, x=0, y=0, radius = 15, circle_color = "black"):
    '''draw the top bigger part of the hat'''
    self.goto(radius*(.75),(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius * 2)+(radius * (0.5)))
    self.pendown()
    self.goto(radius*(.75),(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius * 2)+(radius * 2))
    self.goto(-(radius)*(.75),(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius * 2)+(radius * 2))
    self.goto(-(radius)*(.75),(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius * 2)+(radius * (0.5)))

def bottomCircle(self, x=0, y=0, radius = 15, circle_color = "black"):
    '''draws the bottom circle'''
    self.pendown()
    self.circle(radius * 3)
    self.penup()
def middleCircle(self, x=0, y=0, radius = 15, circle_color = "black"):
    '''draw the middle circle'''
    self.pendown()
    self.circle(radius * 2)
    self.penup()
def topCircle(self, x=0, y=0, radius = 15, circle_color = "black"):
    '''draw the top circle'''
    self.pendown()
    self.circle(radius)
    self.penup()
def drawSnowman(self, x=0, y=0, radius = 15, circle_color = "black"):
    self.bottomCircle()
    self.goto(0,radius * 6)
    self.middleCircle()
    self.goto(0,(radius * 6)+(radius * 4))
    self.topCircle()
    self.goto(-(radius) * (0.5),(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius))
    self.leftEye()
    self.goto((radius) * (0.5),(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius))
    self.rightEye()
    self.goto(0,(radius * 6)+(radius * 4)+(radius))
    self.drawNose()
    self.bottomOfHat()
    self.topOfHat()



t = MyTurtle()
t.hideturtle()
radius = 15
t.drawSnowman(x = 25,y = 25,radius = 25)
```

this is a picture of the snowman when I use the parameters 
t.drawsnowman(x = 25 y=25 radius = 25)
[image: messed up snowman]

this is the snowman when I inuput no parameters t.drawsnowman()
[image: correct snowman]

Comment: you are passing x and y arguments to drawSnowman, but you are not using them inside. I can see that you only use the radius. And what do you mean by drawing does not work?

Comment: You should post compilation output so we can see how in what way it's not working. And I assume you're using this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html (?)

Comment: Yes i am using turtle graphics so  there is not any compilation output because the desired result is a drawn picture, which in this case is a snowman. by drawing does not work I meant that the when I run the program I get different parts of the snowman across the screen. Instead of the three snowballs being together I get 20 pixels of space in between each snowball.

Comment: can you explain why the x and y arguments are not being used inside, I  dont understand why they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going step-by-step and work out what your code actually does (or use a debugger).

- If you call `t.drawSnowman()`, `radius` will `15`.
- You call `bottomCircle()` which will draw a circle with a radius of `radius * 3` = `45`
- You move `radius * 6` = `90` on the y axis (you're now *"on top"* of the circle)
- You call `middleCircle()` which will a circle with a radius of `radius * 2` = `30`
- ...

Now, see what happens if you call your function with parameters:

- If you call `t.drawSnowman(x = 25,y = 25,radius = 25)`, `radius` will `25`.
- You call `bottomCircle()` which will draw a circle with a radius of `radius * 3` = `45`. Note how the local variable `radius` is `15`, since it's the default value of that parameter, and you don't pass the value you passed to `drawSnowman` down to the `bottomCircle` method.
- You move `radius * 6` = `150` on the y axis (you're now *far off* of the circle)
- You call `middleCircle()` which will a circle with a radius of `radius * 2` = `30`. Note how the local variable `radius` is `15`, too.
- ...

So, you problem is that you pass in a value for `radius`, but you use that value only for moving the turtle in `drawSnowman`, not further down in any of the other functions.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was perfect in helping me finish the program. I was caught up looking at the drawing pieces and it distracted me from actually looking at my code to see what was really going on.